# Netbeans 8.2 Can't Verify Git Credentials?

Tags: java, git, netbeans

I have a Java project that I'm making which has had several commits on github. I recently changed OS versions on Kubuntu from 17.10 -> 18.04, and have installed Netbeans 8.2 with Java Version 1.8.0_171 to avoid Java 9+ compatibility issues.

I can't clone the project from git, every time I try to import it using the built in Git "Team" support, my cridentials bounce back. This is mysterious since I use KeePassX to manage all my ID information and directly copy-paste it. I've verified that this is the correct sign in information by signing out on github.com and signing back in only using information in KeePassX, which is successful. I also directly copy the git address into the HTTPS field in Netbeans.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround for this? Is this a well-known error?

Screencap of the error

[image]

**Edit 0:** I've made an exact (And quickly made) video of the process and error, you can find it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W48QD1Tr6GU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: So, what is the exact error that the Netbeans console gives you?

Comment: Do you have 2FA (two factor authentication) activated on your GitHub account?

Comment: @VonC No, I never set that up.

Comment: The exact error is `Incorrect credentials for repository at github.com:SarahSzabo/StellarOPUSConverter.git`

Comment: This problem is still happening with Netbeans 12 in 2020 and there's no improvement in the docs. I can't find any help on it.

Answer (score 1):

> The exact error is

```
Incorrect credentials for repository at github.com:SarahSzabo/StellarOPUSConverter.git
```

That does not look like an https URL (it could be an SSH one, with an `~/.ssh/config` file)

Make sure to copy the https URL:

```
https://github.com/SarahSzabo/StellarOPUSConverter
```

Comment: No Luck, this also didn't work after pasting the URL that you requested. I just verified that the login credentials were correct as a form of sanity check in a chromium private window.

Comment: @SarahSzabo CAn you try with `https://github.com/SarahSzabo/StellarOPUSConverter.git` (adding the trailing .git)

Comment: @SarahSzabo Can you try with the `ssh version git@github.com:SarahSzabo/StellarOPUSConverter.git` (and specify the ssh key path by selecting "Private/Public Key")

Answer (score 0):

This might be quiet old but hope it helps. Had the same issue

In NetBeans you can uncheck " Persist Remote" beside remote name.

Comment: How to, could not find in netbeans 8.2 menu?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning August 13, 2021, we will no longer accept account passwords when authenticating Git operations on GitHub.com

https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Comment: This partially answers the question. But then how about the original question of how to solve it within Netbeans? As the [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) guide says, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30405689)