# Merging changes from a public repository into a private build

Tags: git

Assume I clone a repository `OSS` at version 1.0 containing a class `A`. Subclassing `A` is not enough for me, so I copy `A` to `A'` and make some modifications to it. At a later point in time, I clone `OSS` at version `1.1`, containing an updated version of `A`. How can I merge the changes/updates from `A` to my modified copy `A'`? Is there a standard pattern for such cases?

Comment: Why do you copy `A` instead of directly modificating it? It would be easier to pull the changes from upstream and rebase your modifications on top of them.

Comment: `A` is a UI widget and I need both, the original and a modified version of it

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to:

- create the patch using [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff): [between A#1.0 and 1#1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3211829/6309)

  ```
  git diff 1.0 1.1 -- A > a.patch
  ```
- then apply that patch using the [`patch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) utility: you can specify the file you want to apply the diff to with `patch`.

  ```
  patch -p1 A' a.patch
  ```

On Windows, use a [simplified PATH as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62928104/6309), and you will see patch available:

```
C:\git\>where patch
C:\prgs\gits\current\usr\bin\patch.exe
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I could execute the first command, but failed for the second one, as I am on Windows (no patch command). Any way to apply the patch using Git?

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf If you installed GIT under Windows then launch 'Git Bash' and you will find that you do have a `patch` command.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf I have edited the answer to add the right Windows `%PATH%` for you to use `patch`.

Comment: Thank you both :-) My first limited test looks promising, actually I feared that `patch` would complain because of different class names, but somehow patch seems to be intelligent enough to detect that `A'` is just mentioned at the places were earlier `A` was mentioned, great. I will do some more testing if it also works for more advanced cases.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf Great! Well done. Let us know of your results.