# Apache Netbeans 12.2 with GIT and CAC

Tags: git, netbeans, cac

I work for the Air Force, as such all website activity is HTTPS with CAC client authentication.  I currently develop in Netbeans 12.2 and I am trying to get the native GIT client working with TFS 2015 GIT source code repository.  Since TFS 2015 is using HTTPS with CAC client authentication, I am having a hard time finding any useful information regarding how to configure the GIT client within Netbeans to talk to TFS. Also, since I am on the AF network, I cannot install any applications on my desktop, so I would greatly prefer to use the native capability within Netbeans for GIT.

I did find this SO article: [Cannot use Team -> Git -> Clone wizard in Netbeans 12 to connect to a github repo using SSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62918236/cannot-use-team-git-clone-wizard-in-netbeans-12-to-connect-to-a-github-rep)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is it not possible to request the Git Shell instead?  Being able to get the tools you actually need to be successful is the first fundamental thing that you should be provided, even if you're on a secure network or secure machine.

Comment: Unfortunately no.  :(  The AF has a strict approval process for installing ANY software on their machines.  This process can take over a year or more.  :(

Comment: You may have to go that route.  Finding a solution to this problem in a public capacity where there aren't many of us who've done this before (myself included) isn't going to be as expedient as either asking fellow servicepersons who've done this before or asking to get software you need to do your job installed on your machine.